# JQ turn $('#topspeed').change(function() into a condition

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, option-type

I want to replace

```
$('#topspeed').change(function(){
```

with a condition, something like the following, but working

```
if($("[id=topspeed]").is(":selected")){
```

How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by selected.. Is it a `input` or a `select` element .

Comment: Post the HTML please.

Comment: <select id="topspeed" >
                  <option data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="top"   >- SELECT -</option >
                </select>

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery Docs

> The :selected selector works for <option> elements     It does
>   not work for checkboxes or radio inputs,

You seem to using this directly on the `select` element.

You can write something like this instead

```
if($('#topspeed option[value="1"]').is(":selected")) {
```

**EDIT**

Does not work because of syntax error

```
$('select').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is('#topspeed') {
                               ^------  Missing Closing brace
        alert('Shrubs has been selected')
    })
     ^------ Not supposed to be here
})
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yv7zz/1/)**

Comment: It does not work because the selector is written for value attribute. But your HTML does not have it

Comment: Try this `if($('#topspeed option[data-iconpos="top"]').is(":selected")) {`

Comment: does not work. 
I have also tried removing the icon stuff and using
if($('#topspeed option').is(":selected")) {
but to no avail.

What are the keywords that I could look for online? JQ, select, conditional?

Comment: works but only first time when run. I have tried the following, which worked elsewhere (see the other answer), but something is wrong here.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yv7zz/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
$('select').change(function(){
if($(this).is('#topspeed'))
```

Thank you.